# The word for "to host someone"

Tags: translation, word-requests

I have exhausted google and my many dictionaries. I put "host" or "to host" and don't get the word I'm looking for. The sentence I am trying to say is "are you hosting a new exchange student" and I have no idea where to find the correct terminology. Does anyone know the correct way to approach this. I maybe oversimplifying my search because there may not be an exact word translation. Anyone know how to approach this sentence. This was the closest I found: 受皿となる

Comment: 新しい留学生を泊めていますか？

Comment: I would say 新しい留学生を**受け入れて**いますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy translation of "to host". Depending on the object, you have to choose an appropriate verb.

- to host a conference/formal party: ～を主催する, ～を開催する
- to host a casual party: ～をやる, ～を開く
- to host someone (as a host family): ～を（ホストファミリーとして）受け入れる
- to host someone (as a VIP), to entertain: ～をもてなす
- to host a ceremony/TV progam: ～の司会をする
- to host a website/software: ～をホストする

Actually, ～をホストする may be used by some people who are relatively good at English in any of the contexts above, but I'm reluctant to introduce it as the first-choice.

受け皿となる tends to be used with refugees, disaster victims and such, and it doesn't sound like you host someone actively and willingly.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>A big reason why the following (trans.google) result doesn't sound good is because the question ( "Are you hosting a new exchange student?" )  is usually  asking about immediate future plans.</sub>

> "Are you hosting a new exchange student?"

(trans.google) 「あなたは、新しい交換留学生をホストしていますか？」 <-- This doesn't sound good. But actually, this is a correct, valid translation ...

... because ホストする is used :

- どうしてホストファミリーになるのか - ホームステイ 締切済 | 教えて！goo
  oshiete.goo.ne.jp › 学問・教育 › 留学 › ホームステイ 
  私は留学生をホストするのは、それだけ魅力的なことだと思いますよ。
- detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp › 暮らしと生活ガイド › 2012/02/07 - 日本語を話せない留学生を2週間ホストする場合、

> http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=host+student
>
> host a foreign student === ホームステイの外国人学生を受け入れる

---

> お帰りなさい！ .........  高校留学・10代留学の ...
>
> www.afs.or.jp › イベント＆ニュース
>
> 帰ってくると、ホストファミリーが家にAFSのスタッフや新しい交換留学生を招待し、とても温かい「お帰りなさいパーティー」を開いてくれました。 今回、実に一年半ぶりに帰ったわけですが、私はまだ交換留学生であるかのような感じがしました。 みなさんがいつもの ...

William Colenso Collegeが新しい交換留学生を迎えました！